# How to make GridView to display items with different cellWidth and cellHeight

Tags: qt, gridview, qml, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols2

[image]

I have a model which contains counting number. I want to show that model data in given layout. Please find attached image.

Comment: You should probably use `columnSpan` and `rowSpan`

Comment: But in gridview, cellWidth and cellHeight are same.

Comment: You should update your question regarding this, it's not clear. Can you change to GridLayout?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GridLayout` to span an item across multiple rows/columns

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

GridLayout {
    columnSpacing: 10
    rowSpacing: 10
    columns: 4

    Repeater {

        model: ListModel {
            ListElement { colSpan: 2; rowSpan: 3 }
            ListElement { colSpan: 1; rowSpan: 1 }
            ListElement { colSpan: 1; rowSpan: 1 }
            ListElement { colSpan: 1; rowSpan: 1 }
            ListElement { colSpan: 1; rowSpan: 1 }
            ListElement { colSpan: 1; rowSpan: 1 }
            ListElement { colSpan: 1; rowSpan: 1 }

            ListElement { colSpan: 1; rowSpan: 1 }
            ListElement { colSpan: 1; rowSpan: 1 }
            ListElement { colSpan: 2; rowSpan: 3 }
            ListElement { colSpan: 1; rowSpan: 1 }
            ListElement { colSpan: 1; rowSpan: 1 }
            ListElement { colSpan: 1; rowSpan: 1 }
            ListElement { colSpan: 1; rowSpan: 1 }
        }

        Rectangle {
            Layout.columnSpan: model.colSpan
            Layout.rowSpan: model.rowSpan
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            color: "red"

            Text {
                anchors.fill: parent
                text: index
                horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
            }
        }

    }
}
```